# Using \string in place of underscores satisfies the pgffor's foreach but not the tocloft's addcontentsline

Tags: tocloft, pgffor, underscore

```
%! lualatex --shell-escape 
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,oneside,]{extbook}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for lualatex is used

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[]{tocloft}

\begin{document}
% Some nomenclature: DASH -, SLASH / , UNDERSCORE, UNDERLINE _

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\foreach \cdossier in {circle.c, ctest1.c, check\string_elements.c}
{
  \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\cdossier} % causes the error below (5 lines)
% ! Missing $ inserted.
% <inserted text>
% $
% l.3 \contentsline {chapter}{check_elements.c}{3}
%                                               %
    \inputminted[autogobble]{c}{\cdossier}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

I'm writing a `tex` code which browses all `c` files in the `current working directory` using the `pgffor` package's `\foreach` command.  Because many of the `c` filenames contain underscore, i.e. the `_` symbol, I had to replace the `_` 's with `\string_`

Then using the `tocloft` package, I've tried to make each filename appear as a contents line  by using:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\cfile}
```

But when `\cfile` contains `\string` it gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... {toc}{\protect \contentsline {chapter}{\cfile
                                             }{\thepage }\protected@fil...
```

How to make the filenames containing the underscore character satisfy both the `pgffor` and `tocloft` ?

Comment: the error is unrelated to `_`  you get the same with `\foreach \cdossier in {a,b,c}`  you have simply used `\cfile` without defining it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that error is caused by undefined variable `\cfile` I initially used `\cfile` as the iteration variable of `\foreach` then in a hurry I changed it to `\cdossier` and forgot to change it there. Now I've corrected it. The code gives an error which I think is related to `tocloft` 's not accepting the `\string_` Please refer to the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\string` is not helping as a normal `_` is allowed in file names, but your `.toc` file, with or without `\string`, looks like

```
\contentsline {chapter}{circle.c}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{ctest1.c}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{check_elements.c}{2}{}%
```

so `_` is an error when read back in.

You can use detokenize eg

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,oneside,]{extbook}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for lualatex is used

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[]{tocloft}

\begin{document}
% Some nomenclature: DASH -, SLASH / , UNDERSCORE, UNDERLINE _

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\foreach \cdossier in {circle.c, ctest1.c, check_elements.c}
{
  \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\string\detokenize{\cdossier}} % causes the error below (5 lines)
% ! Missing $ inserted.
% <inserted text>
% $
% l.3 \contentsline {chapter}{check_elements.c}{3}
%                                               %
    \inputminted[autogobble]{c}{\cdossier}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Then (after first deleting the existing toc file) you will get

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\detokenize {circle.c}}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\detokenize {ctest1.c}}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\detokenize {check_elements.c}}{2}{}%
```

[image]